# S.M.A.R.T. prevents HDD disk going into Standby

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, power-management, smart, standby

I use the *Disks* application (preinstaled in Ubuntu 18.04) to configure standby timeout of my HDD disk. By using the *Drive settings... -> Standby* menu I've configured *Standby Timeout* to 15min. The disk goes into standby after 15min of idle state only if I disable S.M.A.R.T. monitoring by using the *SMART Data & Self-Tests* menu. By using the `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdb` command I can force the disk into standby regardless the SMART monitoring is turned on or off.

I want to have SMART monitoring and Standby timeout both enabled, but the features seem to collide with each other.

Is there any way to fix the problem without excess hacking?

Comment: Some HDD have a "spin down when idle" parameter internal to the drive. You can check your drive, and try and set it there.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a monitoring time greater than your standby timeout. As each request to smart attributes reinit the time out.

If you query your smart attributes every hour, a 15 minutes timeout could occurs.
If you query your smart attributes every hour, a 2 hours timeout never occurs.

Comment: How to make the monitoring timeout greater than the standby timeout?

Comment: I don't know you tool. Mine is cacti where I could define the time between to control.
You should use hdparm to control the disk state in order to do not wake it up.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm
I'm not on ubuntu so I can't help more.
I just can explain why it occurs.